# How do I subtract 1 month from date is latest VB.Net (2016)

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a DateTime in VB.Net.  I need to subtract 1 month. I have searched the MS tech support and documentation and found nothing.  I used to use: CDate(DateTime).AddMonths(-1) but that doesn't show in the MS documentation anymore.

Can I still use it or is there a more modern way to do so?

Comment: `myDateTimeVar.AddMonths(-1)`

Comment: [AddMonths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx) is still the right way - not sure what the `CDate` was for if you already had a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Go in to Visual Studio Options > Text Editor > Basic, and make sure that "Hide Advanced Members" is **unchecked**.  If it is greyed out, look under "All Languages" instead of "Basic"

This setting can sometimes cause Intellisense to not list all the members of the class you are working with.